# Keep only one of the duplicated values in the same column and keeping NAs as such as well

Tags: r

I got column like this with some duplicated values

```
    structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), date = c(NA, NA, 
                                                        NA, "2011/01/01", "2011/02/01", "2012/01/01", "2012/01/01", "2012/05/01"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I want to keep only one of the duplicated values, like this

```
structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
               date2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "2011/01/01", "2011/02/01", "2012/01/01", "2012/05/01")), 
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: There aren't any duplicated values in your example, or if you mean the NA than I don't understand your title as that is just a value and doesn't have to specified specificly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want exactly there are multiple alternatives:

```
dat %>% 
   filter(!duplicated(date))
```

gives

```
 id       date
1  1       <NA>
2  1 2011/01/01
3  1 2011/02/01
4  1 2012/01/01
```

As someone else also suggested, it gives the same result as

```
dat %>% distinct(date, .keep_all = T)
```

In contrast to that person I added a column to the distinct function, as I assumed you only want to remove the duplicated dates, not necessary duplicates in other columns (and the .keep_all is than necessary to keep those other columns).

However it is unclear for me if you want to keep all NAs or not. Becuase than you need to add some rows with just the NAs.

if you want all NAs you could for example do:

```
dat %>% 
    filter(!is.na(date) & !duplicated(date)) %>% 
    bind_rows(dat %>% filter(is.na(date)))
```

which gives

```
  id       date
1  1 2011/01/01
2  1 2011/02/01
3  1 2012/01/01
4  1       <NA>
5  1       <NA>
6  1       <NA>
```

Although there probably is a nicer way to do this.

Edit:
If you want to keep the entries but only want to make the duplicated values NA you can use the `duplicated` function this way:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(
    date1 = case_when(
      duplicated(date) ~ NA_character_,
      TRUE ~ date
    )
  )
```

I generally prefer `case_when` over `if_else` due to its readability. But in this case it would be the same.

It results in

```
  id       date      date1
1  1       <NA>       <NA>
2  1       <NA>       <NA>
3  1       <NA>       <NA>
4  1 2011/01/01 2011/01/01
5  1 2011/02/01 2011/02/01
6  1 2012/01/01 2012/01/01
7  1 2012/01/01       <NA>
8  1 2012/05/01 2012/05/01
```

I created an extra column for this example. But you could simply overwrite the date column in your actual analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::distinct`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), date = c(NA, NA, NA, 
                                                  "2011/01/01", "2011/02/01", "2012/01/01")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
df
#>   id       date
#> 1  1       <NA>
#> 2  1       <NA>
#> 3  1       <NA>
#> 4  1 2011/01/01
#> 5  1 2011/02/01
#> 6  1 2012/01/01
df %>%
    distinct()
#>   id       date
#> 1  1       <NA>
#> 2  1 2011/01/01
#> 3  1 2011/02/01
#> 4  1 2012/01/01
```

Comment: Wasn't the idea to keep all the NAs? This only leaves one out of three.

Comment: Yes, This ONLY KEPT ONE NA. I want all the NA to remain. Thanks

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I used the head(). I got now duplicated values.

Comment: @kamrankhan my answer should give you the result, although in a slightly different order. That could easily be solved using a sort/arrange.

Comment: Thanks Annet, you are right it does the job. If I have to insert an NA instead of the duplicated value instead of removing it completely, can I do that?

Comment: @kamrankhan I will change my answer with that